# TypeScript error Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am testing out how to use Context in React but for some reason I cant run the app due the typescript error I get!

**Code:**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';


class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return <Toolbar theme="dark" />;
    }
  }

  function Toolbar(props) {
    // The Toolbar component must take an extra "theme" prop
    // and pass it to the ThemedButton. This can become painful
    // if every single button in the app needs to know the theme
    // because it would have to be passed through all components.
    return (
      <div>
        <ThemedButton theme={props.theme} />
      </div>
    );
  }

  class ThemedButton extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return <button className={'btn btn-' + this.props.theme}></button>;
    }
  }

export default App;
```

**Error I get:**

```
C:/Users/as/Desktop/React - Mobx -Hooks/react-hooks-mobx/src/App.tsx
TypeScript error in C:/Users/iluli/Desktop/React - Mobx -Hooks/react-hooks-mobx/src/App.tsx(11,20):
Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type.  TS7006

     9 |   }
    10 |   
  > 11 |   function Toolbar(props) {
```

Any idea how to fix this and explain the reason why it throws that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to provide the Type for it:

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";

interface IToolbarProps {
  theme: string;
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Toolbar theme="dark" />;
  }
}


// Here in the function
function Toolbar(props: IToolbarProps) {
  // The Toolbar component must take an extra "theme" prop
  // and pass it to the ThemedButton. This can become painful
  // if every single button in the app needs to know the theme
  // because it would have to be passed through all components.
  return (
    <div>
      <ThemedButton theme={props.theme} />
    </div>
  );
}


// HERE as a generic
class ThemedButton extends React.Component<IToolbarProps> {
  render() {
    return <button className={"btn btn-" + this.props.theme}></button>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Sure, happy to help | Can you please mark it answer with an upvote? so that others can easily get aware...

Comment: funy i tried to accept and it said: can't accept in 0 seconds :)